# Resizing a Flash loader after Event.COMPLETE doesn't work

Tags: android, flash, loader, flash-builder

Google suggests that the following is not that uncommon a question: having loaded something into a Flash stage using a Loader, I want to resize it. However, if you do this before the content is loaded, resizing the image causes it to disappear.

The proposed solution is usually to use an Event listener for Event.COMPLETE. Here's my code:

```
public function FlixelTest()
    {
        super();

        // support autoOrients
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        myLoader = new Loader();                     
        myLoader.x = (stage.fullScreenWidth-640)/2;
        myLoader.y = (stage.fullScreenHeight-480)/2;
        addChild(myLoader);                                     

        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("stuff.swf");
        myLoader.load(url);    
        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadProdComplete);


    }

    function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void{
        myLoader.height = 480;
        myLoader.width = 640;
    }
```

According to every posting I can find so far online, this solution should work. When the event fires, the Loader is done, and can be resized. However, it doesn't. Commenting out the lines that modify .height and .width cause the SWF to appear, uncommenting them and running again and the SWF never loads.

Could anything else be interfering here? This is using FlashBuilder to construct an Actionscript3 -> Android project.

EDIT - The solution here doesn't appear to work either: [Problem resizing loader after loading swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780445/problem-resizing-loader-after-loading-swf?rq=1)

UPDATE - I have a working, and horrific, solution that is as followed:

```
function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void{
        if(myLoader.width != 0){
            myLoader.width = 640;
            myLoader.content.width = 640;
        }
        else{
            timer = new Timer(500);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timertick); // there should be a comma here but yahoo replaces it with ... 
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    function timertick(e:TimerEvent){
        timer.stop();
        stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
```

It basically uses the content's width to see if it's finished loading. If it hasn't, it waits a half second and refires the COMPLETE event. This actually helps display it (although the width hasn't been adjusted, I assume that's a separate issue) - I can't believe this is the only way to get it working...

Comment: This is probably not the issue, but I noticed your listener is added after you call `myLoader.load()` ... If the SWF is a local file (appears to be), maybe the load is being completed before the listener is added :) Silly, and probably not the issue...

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I don't think this is the problem in this case, because COMPLETE is definitely firing the function. If anything it's firing it too early! Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not strictly a solution, the way I've circumvented this is by not resizing it at all - I am instead cropping an area over the window so all that's seen is the section I wanted to display.

```
function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void{
        var gameMask : Shape = new Shape;
        gameMask.graphics.beginFill(0xffcc00);
        gameMask.graphics.drawRect(myLoader.x,myLoader.y,640,480);  
        gameMask.graphics.endFill();
        myLoader.content.mask = gameMask;
    }
```

Since the mask would've been necessary for me anyway to hide off-stage clutter, this solved two problems at once.

I won't accept this as the answer in case anyone has any alternative insights, but if anyone comes across this question, this is a posisble solution.